# Strange Behavior for Delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the code below the page will fade in, and then it will fade in the list items on the left, and then its suppose to fade in each thumbnail on the right.  But because of me using .delay() it ends up skipping the loading of some or all of the thumbnails.  Is there something else other than .delay() I can use to halt the execution of the thumbs fading in before they should begin to?

```
//Showcase
    $('#showcase').animate({'opacity' : 0}, 0);
    fadeInDivs(['#showcase']);
    function fadeInDivs(els) {
        e = els.pop();
        $(e).   delay(750).animate({'opacity' : 1}, 1000, function(){
            if (els.length) fadeInDivs(els);
        });
    };

    $('#showcase').queue(function(){

        //fade in each filter
        $('#filters li').each(function(i, item) {
            setTimeout(function() { $(item).animate({'opacity' : 1}, 1000); }, 50 * i);
        });

        //fade in each thumbnail
        $('.thumb').delay(1000).each(function(i, item) {
            setTimeout(function() { $(item).animate({'opacity' : 1}, 1000); }, 500 * i);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtwebb/D9xVc/6/). I think this what you're looking for. Let me know if it's not. Here is the jQuery code:

```
    $('#showcase').queue(function() {
    var i = 0;
    var length = $('#filters li').length;
    //fade in each filter
    $('#filters li').each(function(i) {

        //alert(i);
        $(this).delay(750*i).animate({
            'opacity': 1
        }, 1000, function() {
            if (i == length) {
                //fade in each thumbnail
                $('.thumb').each(function(i) {
                    $(this).delay(750 * i).animate({
                        'opacity': 1
                    }, 1000);
                });
            }
        });
        i++;
    });

});
```

Comment: im trying to get #filters li to fade in and then when that is done i want the .thumbs to fade in.. heres a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UsXWn/  as u see the photos start fading in before the filters are complete

Comment: @JoeBobby - I updated the fiddle. See if that's more to your liking.

Comment: is there a way to do it by just changing the part in the .queue()? And is there a reason why you changed from animate to fadeIn?

Comment: @joebobby - I updated the fiddle again. The reason I used fadeIn was because it's a bit easier to read and it does the same thing. But I updated it just rearranging the code you had.

Comment: this seems to be the type of effect im looking for thank you!